# Filter for comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm pretty new to Scala and am having trouble writing this filter function.

Basically I have two Lists:

(1) `TicketList` which has `Ticket` as a member, which in turn has `Event` as a member which in turn has a field called `Attribute` which is a `Map[String, String]` one of whose keys is `EventReady` evaluating to true/false.

Pictorally this looks like

`TicketList -> Ticket -> Event -> Attribute.get("EventReady")`

(2) `EventList` which has `Event` as a member which has the same fields.

`EventList -> Event -> Attribute.get("EventReady")`

I want to filter a for comprehension by NOT returning the values when 
`ticketList.event != eventList.event && event.attribute.get("EventReady") == false` but am having tremendous difficulty doing this.

The general gist of what I have is

```
           ...//for comprehension logic

      } yield (ticketList, eventList)
    }
  .filter(

    (i: TicketList, k: List[SummaryByEvent]) =>

      i.tickets.flatMap(x => List(x.event)).diff(k.flatMap(x => List(x.event))) // returns List[Event]
        .filter(p => p.dynamicAttribute.get.get("TICKETHOLDER_ONLY") == Some("true")) // also returns List[Event]
```

But, this just returns a list of events that I want to filter by and not a Boolean (which I obviously need). How do I filter by the intersection of my for comprehension and my list?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Being able to describe a problem is half way to solving it. So you have a collection of tuples. It doesn't matter how the collection was created, `for` comprehension or otherwise. And you want to filter it. Mock up two very simple, trivial, `(TicketList,List[SummaryByEvent])` tuples, one that _should_ pass the filter and one that should not. That will give us, the readers, a very good idea of what you're dealing with. Then describe how the example is too simple and how your goal is actually more complicated.